# GitHub Jekyll: image in the same line as text in preview but not in published version

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to create a text that contains small images in the same line but this doesn't seem to be possible, at least using Markup. I get a nice preview but then the published version shows images in a new line.

This is the text in my post:

```
When **p** is true and **q** is true, **p ![and](/assets/and.jpg) q** is also true.
```

which in the preview shows as I expect it to:

[image: preview]

but then, once published it shows like this:

[image: published]

Is there a way to get the images to be displayed as in the preview?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add some css:

```
img {display: inline!important;}
```

Better is to NOT use !important, but use the proper [specificity](https://specifishity.com/). As you are not showing any context, the proper selectors are impossible to guess.